# Includes in inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, operating-system, inline-assembly

We are working on a toy operating system as a assignment for a class.
I'm having some trouble with writing of the kernel panic function.

It should save all registers, call some printf-like function, then print the saved registers and halt the cpu. Right now it's defined as a macro:

```
#define panic(...) \
    do{ \
        asm volatile("SAVE_REGISTERS %1\n\t" : "m="(_panic_context)); \
        _panic_printk(&_panic_context, __VA_ARGS__); \
    while(0)
```

`_panic_context` is a global variable that contains saved registers of a thread and some more stuff. The problem is with `SAVE_REGISTERS`. It is a macro defined somewhere in an assembler header file, but I don't know how to include it. Simple #include in the file obviously doesn't work. I've tried googling and writing funny and desperate stuff (like #include in the assembler strings :-) ) but nothing helped. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

We're using GCC and compile for MIPS (running in a simulator :-) )

edit:
`SAVE_REGISTERS` is defined with `.macro SAVE_REGISTERS`... . It can't be in a C macro, because it's used in other assembly modules.
I can't make a .S file with it, because panic has to be variadic. Or at least I couldn't come up with any other way to do it.

Comment: How exactly is `SAVE_REGISTERS` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how macros work. They get expanded before any other compiling happens. You can't use `asm` to emit some code which contains a macro because that macro will never be expanded.

Instead you might try defining `SAVE_REGISTERS` as a C macro which uses the `asm` statement to build your assembly code:

```
#define SAVE_REGISTERS(x) \
   asm volatile ("movx ax, %1", ...);
```

then you can do

```
#define panic(...) \
do { \
    SAVE_REGISTERS(_panic_context); \
    _panic_printk(&_panic_context, __VA_ARGS__); \
} while(0);
```

Comment: The dummy do-loop is to make sure there's a semicolon after the macro, methinks.

Comment: The dummy do-loop is a common technique in multi-statement macros that makes them behave well when used in `if` statements, for example.  It should be left in the macro (but the closing brace should be added).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr

Comment: Ah OK, I wasn't aware of that convention. Edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a MIPS system lying around, but on my x86 loonix box I tried `#include` and discovered that `#` is the comment character, so I tried `.include` and that worked as soon as I quoted the file name:  `.include "something.i"`.

Now, if you have header files and an organized infrastructure for assembler code, I have to wonder why you want to do this with inline asm in the first place, though. Why not just make a real `.s` or `.S` file, include the assembler header file, and make it a first-class module in your system?

I've seen small masterpieces done with **asm** even in projects that already had a `locore.S` in their `Makefile`, go figure...